# How to use multiple ssh keys with different accounts and hosts

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent, github

i have multiple ssh keys and i have also have account on bitbucket and github. how when ever i use pull it gives me error

```
:/var/www/proj$ git pull origin master
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

or if i ssh the bitbucket website it gives errors ass public key denied

```
:~$ ssh git@bitbucket.org
Permission denied (publickey).
```

how can i get this resolved and use different keys with different accounts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is all gathered from website and stackoverflow, hope this helps who are new to ssh

so you can have many ssh keys

```
~/.ssh$ ls
yyy_id_rsa  yyy_id_rsa.pub  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Note: we need to add then to the ssh-agent, probably id_rsa will be added so we need to add the other private key

```
~/.ssh$ ssh-add yyy_id_rsa
```

now we have added both ssh keys to ssh-agent

we have one for bitbucket and one for github

so we create a config file like this

```
~/.ssh$ nano config
Host bit-yyyuser bitbucket.org
Hostname bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yyy_id_rsa
User yyyuser

Host bit-xxxuser bitbucket.org
Hostname bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
User xxxuser

Host git-xxxuser github.com
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
User xxxuser
```

Note: I am using 2 different keys for 2 different account on bitbucket and one for github.

Now we need to tell the git repository which host to use so that I will get that specific ssh key for that specific account

change `git@bitbucket.orgyyyuser/yyyproject.git` to `git@bit-yyyuser:yyyuser/yyyproject.git`

so in the project folder and add the remote url

```
/var/www/yyyproject$ git remote add bit git@bit-yyyuser:yyyuser/yyyproject.git
```

in other project

```
/var/www/xxxproject$ git remote add bitt git@bit-xxxuser:xxxuser/xxxproject.git
```

now you can use push and pull easily

```
:/var/www/yyyproject$ git pull bit master
From bit-yyyuser:yyyuser/yyyproject
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
:/var/www/yyyproject$
```

and another project

```
/var/www/xxxproject$ git push bitt ver1
To git@bit-xxxuser:xxxuser/xxxproject.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
:/var/www/xxxproject$
```

now I dont have the github project on the local machine so we need to clone the project
but we need to make a little change to the url to clone

our url is like this

```
git@github.com:xxxuser/python.git
```

as we have to clone it with specific keys we just need to change the host name with the host we have defined

```
git@git-xxxuser:xxxuser/python.git
```

as defined in the config file

and now we can clone

```
:/var/www/us$ git clone git@git-xxxuser:xxxuser/python.git
Cloning into 'python'...
remote: Counting objects: 75, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
remote: Total 75 (delta 18), reused 62 (delta 8)
Receiving objects: 100% (75/75), 6.29 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (18/18), done.
:/var/www/us$
```

we have identified different ssh keys for different host, one for git and one for bitbucket
now the system knows which ssh keys to be used with which host.

Now we can easily pull, push.

Comment: What if my git URL is using https? Anyway to work on that?

Answer (score 1):

I configure `~/.ssh/config`, like this:

```
Host gitlab-as-thuc  
    HostName git.thuc.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.thuc
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

then use custom hostname instead of real domain in git url:

```
git remote add thuc git@gitlab-as-thuc:your-repo.git
```

For more detail please read here: http://itblog.study.land/how-to-specify-different-ssh-keys-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain/